# Evaluating a math expression with variables. (java 8)

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, recursive-descent

I would like additional help on a answer to this question,   [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227947/4825796).  The user @Boann answered the question with a very interesting algorithm that he also points out can be altered to accept variables.  I've managed to alter it and get it to work, **but dont know how he separates the compilation and evaluation**.  Here's my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EvaluateExpressionWithVariabels {

@FunctionalInterface
interface Expression {
    double eval();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String,Double> variables = new HashMap<>();     
    for (double x = 100; x <= +120; x++) {
        variables.put("x", x);
        System.out.println(x + " => " + eval("x+(sqrt(x))",variables).eval());
    }
}

public static Expression eval(final String str,Map<String,Double> variables) {
    return new Object() {
        int pos = -1, ch;

        //if check pos+1 is smaller than string length ch is char at new pos
        void nextChar() {
            ch = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
        }

        //skips 'spaces' and if current char is what was searched, if true move to next char return true
        //else return false
        boolean eat(int charToEat) {
            while (ch == ' ') nextChar();
            if (ch == charToEat) {
                nextChar();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


        Expression parse() {
            nextChar();
            Expression x = parseExpression();
            if (pos < str.length()) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            return x;
        }

        // Grammar:
        // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
        // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor
        // factor = `+` factor | `-` factor | `(` expression `)`
        //        | number | functionName factor | factor `^` factor

        Expression parseExpression() {
            Expression x = parseTerm();
            for (;;) {
                if (eat('+')) { // addition
                    Expression a = x, b = parseTerm();                      
                    x = (() -> a.eval() + b.eval());
                } else if (eat('-')) { // subtraction
                    Expression a = x, b = parseTerm();
                    x = (() -> a.eval() - b.eval());
                } else {
                    return x;
                }
            }
        }

        Expression parseTerm() {
            Expression x = parseFactor();
            for (;;) {
                if (eat('*')){
                     Expression a = x, b = parseFactor(); // multiplication
                     x = (() -> a.eval() * b.eval());
                }
                else if(eat('/')){
                     Expression a = x, b = parseFactor(); // division
                     x = (() -> a.eval() / b.eval());
                }
                else return x;
            }
        }

        Expression parseFactor() {
            if (eat('+')) return parseFactor(); // unary plus
            if (eat('-')){
                Expression b = parseFactor(); // unary minus
                return (() -> -1 * b.eval());
            }

            Expression x;
            int startPos = this.pos;
            if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
                x = parseExpression();
                eat(')');
            } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
                while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.'){                     
                    nextChar();
                }
                double xx = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(startPos, this.pos));
                x = () -> xx;
            } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // functions
                while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') nextChar();
                String func = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);

                if ( variables.containsKey(func)){
                    x = () -> variables.get(func);
                }else{
                    double xx = parseFactor().eval();
                    if (func.equals("sqrt")) x = () -> Math.sqrt(xx);
                    else if (func.equals("sin")) x = () -> Math.sin(Math.toRadians(xx));
                    else if (func.equals("cos")) x = () -> Math.cos(Math.toRadians(xx));
                    else if (func.equals("tan")) x = () -> Math.tan(Math.toRadians(xx));                    
                    else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
                }
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            }

            if (eat('^')){ 
                x = () -> {
                    double d =  parseFactor().eval();
                    return Math.pow(d,d); // exponentiation
                };
            }

            return  x;
        }
    }.parse();
}
}
```

If you take a look at his answer his main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Double> variables = new HashMap<>();
    Expression exp = parse("x^2 - x + 2", variables);
    for (double x = -20; x <= +20; x++) {
        variables.put("x", x);
        System.out.println(x + " => " + exp.eval());
    }
}
```

He calls function `parse` on this line `Expression exp = parse("x^2 - x + 2", variables);` to compile the expression once and uses the for to evaluate it multiple times with a unique x values.  What does the `parse` function refer to.

ps: I have commented on the users question with no reply.

Comment: "What does the parse function refer to"
`Expression parse() {
            nextChar();
            Expression x = parseExpression();
            if (pos < str.length()) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            return x;
        }`

Comment: I dont believe thats correct because that function is not visible to main and the `parse` function hes calling takes two parameters @Thibstars

Comment: You're right. Shouldn't it be `eval()`?

Comment: If call `eval()` instead of parse it attempts to solve the equation and if `variables` does not contain `x` i get an error. @Thibstars

Comment: Without trying, I believe that the sample code of the other question has had some refactoring. That the `variables` are putted after the `Expression` has been initialized, means that the expression had some kind of memory, which it does not have now anymore. So you only need to call `eval(String, Map)` inside the loop. The `parse` before is not needed.

Comment: Wait.. The code for the expression, which has the memory effect, was probably not yet included in the answer. So you can implement it yourself, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Roland im not really understanding what you're saying.  Could you make a more detailed answer.  Also In his awnser he says `What if, having added support for variables, you wanted to evaluate the same expression millions of times with changed variables, without parsing it every time? It's possible. First define an interface to use to evaluate the precompiled expression`.  Wouldnt removing parse on top and just calling `eval(String, Map)` inside the for loop parse it every iteration.

Comment: sorry... was using my mobile to read and write, which wasn't such a good idea ;-) Will prepare an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. The "`parse`" function I referred to is simply the existing `eval` function, but renamed since it returns an `Expression` object.

So you'd have:

```
public static Expression parse(String str, Map<String,Double> variables) { ... }
```

And invoke it by:

```
Map<String,Double> variables = new HashMap<>();
Expression exp = parse("x+(sqrt(x))", variables);
for (double x = 100; x <= +120; x++) {
    variables.put("x", x);
    System.out.println(x + " => " + exp.eval());
}
```

One other thing: It's necessary to know at parse time whether a name refers to a variable or a function, in order to know whether or not it takes an argument, but you can't call `containsKey` on the variables map during the parse, since the variables might not be present in the map until `exp.eval()` is called! One solution is to put functions in a map instead, so you can call `containsKey` on that:

```
    } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // functions and variables
        while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') nextChar();
        String name = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
        if (functions.containsKey(name)) {
            DoubleUnaryOperator func = functions.get(name);
            Expression arg = parseFactor();
            x = () -> func.applyAsDouble(arg.eval());
        } else {
            x = () -> variables.get(name);
        }
    } else {
```

And then somewhere at class level, initialize the `functions` map:

```
private static final Map<String,DoubleUnaryOperator> functions = new HashMap<>();
static {
    functions.put("sqrt", x -> Math.sqrt(x));
    functions.put("sin", x -> Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)));
    functions.put("cos", x -> Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x)));
    functions.put("tan", x -> Math.tan(Math.toRadians(x)));
}
```

(It would also be okay to define the `functions` map as a local variable inside the parser, but that adds a little bit more overhead during each parse.)

Comment: Thanks alot. This option is much faster than using javscript.

Answer (score 2):

I think the actual code of the `Expression` which holds the map reference was not published on the answer.

In order for that sample code to work the expression must have some kind of memory. Actually the code manipulates the map and as the expression holds a reference to it, each subsequent call to the expression's `eval`-method will take the adjusted value.

So in order to get the code working you will first need an expression implementation, which holds a map reference. But beware of any sideeffects, which such an expression may have.

So for that specific example, the code must be something like the following (don't have time to completely look whether it will work, but you will get the idea: the important thing is, that the expression holds a reference which is altered from outside):

```
static Expression parse(String expression, Map<String, String> variables) {
    return new PseudoCompiledExpression(expression, variables);
}
static class PseudoCompiledExpression implements Expression {
    Map<String, String> variables;
    Expression wrappedExpression;
    PseudoCompiledExpression(String expression, Map<String, String> variables) {
       this.variables = variables;
       wrappedExpression = eval(expression, variables);
    }
   public double eval() {
        // the state of the used map is altered from outside... 
        return wrappedException.eval();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but Boann clarified his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the above grammar to not work for exponentiation. This one works:

```
public class BcInterpreter {

static final String BC_SPLITTER = "[\\^\\(\\/\\*\\-\\+\\)]";
static Map<String,Double> variables = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<String,DoubleUnaryOperator> functions = new HashMap<>();

static {
    functions.put("sqrt", x -> Math.sqrt(x));
    functions.put("sin", x -> Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)));
    functions.put("cos", x -> Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x)));
    functions.put("tan", x -> Math.tan(Math.toRadians(x)));
    functions.put("round", x -> Math.round(x));
    functions.put("abs", x -> Math.abs(x));
    functions.put("ceil", x -> Math.ceil(x));
    functions.put("floor", x -> Math.floor(x));
    functions.put("log", x -> Math.log(x));
    functions.put("exp", x -> Math.exp(x));
    // TODO: add more unary functions here.
}

/**
 * Parse the expression into a lambda, and evaluate with the variables set from fields
 * in the current row.  The expression only needs to be evaluated one time.
 * @param recordMap
 * @param fd
 * @param script
 * @return
 */
static String materialize(Map<String, String> recordMap, FieldDesc fd, String script){
    // parse the expression one time and save the lambda in the field's metadata
    if (fd.get("exp") == null) {
        fd.put("exp", parse(script, variables));
    }
    // set the variables to be used with the expression, once per row
    String[] tokens = script.split(BC_SPLITTER);
    for(String key : tokens) {
        if (key != null) {
            String val = recordMap.get(key.trim());
            if (val != null)
                variables.put(key.trim(), Double.parseDouble(val));
        }
    }
    // evaluate the expression with current row's variables
    return String.valueOf(((Expression)(fd.get("exp"))).eval());
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Expression {
    double eval();
}

static Map<String,Double> getVariables(){
    return variables;
}

public static Expression parse(final String str,Map<String,Double> variables) {
    return new Object() {
        int pos = -1, ch;

        //if check pos+1 is smaller than string length ch is char at new pos
        void nextChar() {
            ch = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
        }

        //skips 'spaces' and if current char is what was searched, if true move to next char return true
        //else return false
        boolean eat(int charToEat) {
            while (ch == ' ') nextChar();
            if (ch == charToEat) {
                nextChar();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        Expression parse() {
            nextChar();
            Expression x = parseExpression();
            if (pos < str.length()) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            return x;
        }

        // Grammar:
        // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
        // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor
        // factor = base | base '^' base
        // base = '-' base | '+' base | number | identifier | function factor | '(' expression ')'

        Expression parseExpression() {
            Expression x = parseTerm();
            for (;;) {
                if (eat('+')) { // addition
                    Expression a = x, b = parseTerm();
                    x = (() -> a.eval() + b.eval());
                } else if (eat('-')) { // subtraction
                    Expression a = x, b = parseTerm();
                    x = (() -> a.eval() - b.eval());
                } else {
                    return x;
                }
            }
        }

        Expression parseTerm() {
            Expression x = parseFactor();
            for (;;) {
                if (eat('*')){
                    Expression a = x, b = parseFactor(); // multiplication
                    x = (() -> a.eval() * b.eval());
                } else if(eat('/')){
                    Expression a = x, b = parseFactor(); // division
                    x = (() -> a.eval() / b.eval());
                } else {
                    return x;
                }
            }
        }

        Expression parseFactor(){
            Expression x = parseBase();
            for(;;){
                if (eat('^')){
                    Expression a = x, b = parseBase();
                    x = (()->Math.pow(a.eval(),b.eval()));
                }else{
                    return x;
                }
            }
        }
        Expression parseBase(){
            int startPos = this.pos;
            Expression x;
            if (eat('-')){
                Expression b = parseBase();
                x = (()-> (-1)*b.eval());
                return x;
            }else if (eat('+')){
                x = parseBase();
                return x;
            }
            if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
                x = parseExpression();
                eat(')');
                return x;
            } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
                while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.'){
                    nextChar();
                }
                double xx = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(startPos, this.pos));
                x = () -> xx;
                return x;
            } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') { // functions and variables
                while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') nextChar();
                String name = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
                if (functions.containsKey(name)) {
                    DoubleUnaryOperator func = functions.get(name);
                    Expression arg = parseFactor();
                    x = () -> func.applyAsDouble(arg.eval());
                } else {
                    x = () -> variables.get(name);
                }
                return x;
            }else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            }
        }
    }.parse();
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, i just tested negative exponents and they do not seem to work correctly but positive ones do.  Although i will not need it, it is good to know. thanks

Comment: " Expression arg = parseFactor(); "  ideally, should parse the args as a complete expression. like Expression arg  = parseExpression(); and then eat(')');